# Using position: 'Absolute' and display: 'None' in React Native still renders the component

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I've came across an issue in React Native and that is when using position: 'Absolute' and display: 'None' on a component, the component still renders. I should note that this happens in Android only (iOS this works as expected)
Any ideas on what I should do in this case?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18415) that was reported some time ago and unfortunately has not been resolved. You can easily work around it with conditional rendering, e.g.

```
{this.state.isShowingComponent && (
          <MyComponent />
)}
```